# What is the appropriate term for a "non-empty soybean pod" in Agronomy?

Tags: synonyms

I'm currently helping my cousin translating from Indonesian to English. We're stumped on the correct term for a "non-empty soybean pod".

While I personally think that "non-empty pod" would suffice, I think that there should be a less mathematical term for it.

I mean as "empty pod" has another term, which is "flat pod", wouldn't there also be a special term for the non-empty ones?

Thanks in advance. :)

Edit: I got the term "flat pod" from [here](http://www.bioone.org/doi/abs/10.1093/jee/tov145). It's a link to a scientific paper in agronomy. "Flat pod" was meant for something along this line "soybean pods with aborted seeds"

Comment: Please link (a dictionary definition) to the definition of 'flat pod' you cite. I can't find many examples of "flat pod" on the internet after filtering out false positives. You may well be stuck with 'full / part-filled / non-empty soybean pod'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Virgnia Tech has [this webpage](https://blogs.ext.vt.edu/soybean-update/2013/10/17/flat-pods-showing-up-in-virginias-soybean-crop/) from 2013 which discusses the problem of 'flat' pods and contains the following quote when discussing photos of pods:

> a selection from full season with **full** pods on top and various **flats** on bottom

Virginia Tech, therefore, seem to accept 'full' as the opposite of 'flat' when discussing soya bean pods and referring to pods which actually contain beans. 'Full' seems to be an accepted term.